# unable to correct format date in java

Tags: java, date

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdff = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date start = sdff.parse("10/10/2009");
        Date end = sdff.parse("10/10/2009");
        System.out.println(start+"..."+end);
```

the output is

```
Sat Oct 10 00:00:00 EDT 2009...Sat Oct 10 00:00:00 EDT 2009
```

instead of `10/10/2009`
Why does this happen? MM is the month, dd and yyyy should be correct but why does it not output the expected format?

Comment: What output do you expect and why? Did you check `toString` method of `Date` class?

Comment: i was expecting 10/10/2009   since the format was MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: And as Pshemo asked, did you look at the Date.toString documentation?

Comment: You are printing `Date` instance which means you are using result of its `toString()` method. Purpose of this class is to remember point in time, not format you want to use to print it (for that we have `DateFormat`s).

Comment: You fommatted String to Date by method `sdff.parse()`

            Date start = sdff.parse("10/10/2009");

Here `start` is a date, you printed it directly, that's why you got output like `Sat Oct 10 00:00:00 EDT 2009`. To format Date to String, you need the method sdff.format(). This is what you expected:

            String startDate = sdff.format(start);

Then you can output `startDate` the String as your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the class [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) does is conversion between the classes [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) according to your specifications. But the resulting Date object is unaware of the SimpleDateFormat it was created by. It stores the date in its internal format. When you pass a Date to println, it will appear in the default date format.

When you want to use your custom SimpleDateFormat also for formating the output, you need to use it again for converting the Date to a String:

```
System.out.println(sdff.format(start) + "..." + sdff.format(end));
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the SimpleDateFormat to create the output, as in

```
System.out.println(sdff.format(start)+"..."+sdff.format(end));
```

Answer (score 2):

You must format when you print:

```
System.out.println(sdff.format(start)+"..."+sdff.format(end));
```

Comment: look's like we have to flip a coin, bro... your answer appeared pretty much concurrently with mine

Answer (score 1):

The output of `System.out.println(start+"..."+end);` is done using the method `toString` of the class `Date`.

If you need to get a string in the form `MM/dd/yyyy` simply apply the method `format` (of your sdff) to the `Date` instance.

```
System.out.println(sdff.format(start)+"..."+sdff.format(end));
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct answers already posted, but FWIW, here's another:

SimpleDateFormat has a parse(String s) method for converting a String to a Date

SimpleDateFormat also has a format(Date d) method for converting a Date to a String.

But you were only using the parse method, you were not using the format method to output the dates, hence they were output in the default way, using Date.toString()